# How to Assign Image to object for Saving in Database

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I want to Save image to Database.The image is selected by Browsing and is loaded to Imagebox in silverlight application in C#.Net.
I want to assign this loaded image to Object that is used to Saving the data.
Below is my Code.

```
private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
OpenFileDialog objFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            bool? IsSelected = objFileDialog.ShowDialog();
            objFileDialog.Filter = "Pictures (*.jpg)|*.jpg";
            objFileDialog.FilterIndex = 1;
            if (IsSelected == true)
            {

                BitmapImage bitImage = new BitmapImage();
                bitImage.SetSource(objFileDialog.File.OpenRead());
                image1.Source = bitImage;
                //Image1 is object of Image
            }  
}
```

Code of Object that is carrying Data to Save Method in Service File.

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

      var objData = new ServiceReference1.Data_Registration();
      objData .AY_ID = newAcadYearId;
      objData .CellNo = txtCellNo.Text;
      objData .ImageId = ;
      services.DataRegAsync(objAlumni);
    }
```

**Please Suggest how can i assign Selected Image to my Object objdata.**